Need Ubuntu with PHP 7.4
I have a client with a website that requires PHP 7.4 to run some custom code.  In order to test fixes, I need create a local VM that can run 7.4, but this version is no longer available for installation—as far as I’ve been able to determine.  My hope is to be able to find an image with 7.4 pre-installed that I can run under either VirtualBox or VMWare Fusion.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

You can use the php PPA maintained by ondrej. It only supports LTS versions of Ubuntu. To install php7.4, open a terminal and run the commands
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php7.4


Thanks!  I tried this exact thing on an existing Ubuntu 23 VM and it didn’t work (couldn’t find some dependencies).  I installed a fresh version Ubuntu 24 server, and it installed!

@mpemburn The PPA is only available on supported LTS versions of Ubuntu. 23.X is not LTS and it has reached end of support earlier this year.

The Ubuntu LTS versions are even numbered: 18.04, 20.04, 22.04, 24.04, etc.

Just make a clone of what you got, change IP, Hostname problem solved. If these are Publicly exposed though I would either recommend updating the code that supports PHP8.4 or look for something else that does similar but supports latest versions of PHP.
Regards
